# Execution Time of JUnit Test class with @BeforeAll in Gradle report

Tags: java, gradle, junit

In order to track full time of test execution, I would like to track all tests per class with @BeforeAll or @AfterAll methods. When tests is done, Gradle generates html-report with tests duration but excluding preparation methods, such as those, who marked as @BeforeAll.
For example, there is next Test class

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class TestWithLongBeforeAll {

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    void testMathGrade() {
        Assertions.assertThat(2 + 2).isEqualTo(4);
    }

    @Test
    void testHighMathGrade() {
        Assertions.assertThat(3 + 3).isEqualTo(4);
    }
}
```

As a result, all test duration is near 0.2 seconds. Here is report screenshot, generated by gradle: [report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0VqL.jpg)

*Is there any way to make junit track full test lifecycle per class?*

Answer (score 0):

You can change the setup method into a test, and use a MethodOrderer to make sure it is run first.  The annotated setup method will be run before all un-annotated tests.

```
...
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class TestWithLongBeforeAll {

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void setUp() {
        Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    ...
}
```